# Show text on span click

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to to display a link and then show other links below it if a span is clicked. I've found other examples of this here but my doesn't work for some reason. Would someone take a look, please? Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/kksd014q/). And here is my code. There are two problems:

1 - The sub-links should be hidden on first load.

2 - When more is clicked nothing happens. This will have a toggle comman eventually but I want to get the basic code working first.

```
    <script>
    $(".kids").hide();
    $("#more-kids").click(function() {
     alert('showing'); 
    });
    </script>


    <div class="information">
      <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Terms</a></span>
      <span id="more-kids">more</span><br />
      <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">First Child</a></span>
      <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/15.html">Second Chlld</a></span>   
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by sub-links? Do you mean `class=kids`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Those links should not show until "more" is clicked on. And then they should hide if more is clicked again.

Comment: @user3052443 do you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kksd014q/4/

Comment: in your jsfiddle example the jQuery is missing. If you add it its work fine https://jsfiddle.net/kksd014q/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add jQuery library to your jsfiddle code:
So add it, your basic code will work.

And your desire this code is:

```
$(".kids").hide();
$("#more-kids").click(function() {
 $(".kids").toggle();
});
```

**Preview link:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/LOrpQj

Answer (score 3):

You need to add jQuery into your jsfiddle. You can go to Javascript properties (button on left high corner of javascript box), then select "JQuery 3.2.1" on Frameworks & Extensions. 
It's better connecting jQuery libraries using html script tag, so you can copy this to your project, out of jsfiddle, as i done in this example. 
The code I wrote shows and hides links when the span with id `more-kids` is clicked.

```js
$("#more-kids").click(function() {
 $(".kids").toggle(); //shows or hides links
});
```

```css
.kids{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="information">
  <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Terms</a></span>
  <span id="more-kids">more</span><br />
  <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">First Child</a></span>
  <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/15.html">Second Child</a></span>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine. All you need to make it work is to add any jQuery version to your jsfiddle.

[image]

If you want to use jQuery in a local project, you can load it via CDN or if you don't mind downloading jQuery, you can also load it from your local storage.

This would look like:

```js
$(".kids").hide();
$("#more-kids").click(function() { 
 alert('showing');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <!-- use CDN or put the path of your downloaded jquery-min.js file into the source attribute -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="information">
    <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Terms</a></span>
    <span id="more-kids">more</span><br />
    <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">First Child</a></span>
    <span class="kids"><a href="http://example.com/15.html">Second Chlld</a></span>   
  </div>
</body>
```